# Does $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$ have a general solution in terms of arbitrary functions of $x$ and $t$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm currently learning about PDEs in a math course in my program and was wondering about the general solution to $u_{xx}=u_{tt}$, where $u$ is a function of only $x$ and $t$, implying that both derivatives are equal to an arbitrary constant, which I denoted as $\lambda$ below.

I was able to find examples showing that $u_{xt}=0 \implies u(x, t) = F(x)+G(t)$ and $u_{xt}=x \implies u(x,t) = \frac{-tx^2}{2}+F(x)+G(t)$, but how can this be extended to non-mixed partial derivatives?

I attempted the same with the equation in question and got stuck at $u(x,t)=\frac{\lambda}{2}x^2+g_0(t)x+g1(t)=\frac{\lambda}{2}t^2+f_0(x)t+f_1(x)$. I think this is wrong but I don't know why. What am I missing?

Comment: This is the "wave equation" in one space dimension.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#Wave_equation_in_one_space_dimension ...Solution $u(x,t) = F(x-t)+G(x+t)$

Comment: What do you mean with your first paragraph? The equation $u_{xx} = u_{tt}$ does *not* imply that $u_{xx} = u_{tt} = \lambda$ where $\lambda$ is a constant.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't? My bad. What else can it equal?